# How can I assign an element of the array to a new key in the document on MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a problem with MongoDB.
I have a collection with many documents like this:

```
{
key1:[   
        {el:"EL1"},
        {el:"EL2"} 
     ]
}
```

I want to update all documents in the collection `col` adding a new key `key2` where the value is `key1.0`. 
In particular a generic output's document will be:

```
{
key1:[   
        {el:"EL1"},
        {el:"EL2"} 
     ],
key2: {el:"EL1"}   
}
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to generate new field based on `key1.0` value and then you can run [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to update existing collection with the result of aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "key2.el": { 
                $let: {
                    vars: { fst: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$key1", 0 ] } },
                    in: "$$fst.el"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "col" }
])
```